# Separate front-end and back-end apps on same domain

Tags: api, .htaccess

I have two different application for frontend and backend. I want to deploy both of them on the same server.

So when the url is like mydomian.com/users, it should point to frontend app and when url is like mydomian.com/api/users, it should point to backend app.

I have tried creating htaccess rules for this purpose it is not working

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^api backend-directory [NC]
RewriteRule ^ frontend-directory [NC]
```

Is it possible deploy both frontend and backend on the same server or they should be on different server?

Comment: So the frontend and backend apps are in two separate directories off the document root? What is the front-controller that handles the responses in both cases? What do you mean exactly by "not working"?

Comment: Both frontend and backend will be in different directories and will have their respective index file which will server the request. The request is not redirected to `backend-directory` when url has `/api` path. It is always pointing to `frontend-directory` as per the htaccess code in question

Comment: Do you have additional .htaccess files in the backend and frontend subdirectories that contain mod_rewrite directives?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have additional `.htaccess` files in the backend and frontend subdirectories (to route the request to the respective front-controllers) then in the root `.htaccess` file you would need something like the following (Apache 2.4):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^api($|/) backend-directory/ [END]
RewriteRule ^ frontend-directory/ [END]
```

You need the trailing slash on the end of the directory being rewritten to otherwise mod_dir will issue an external 301 redirect to append the trailing slash and your hidden directory will be exposed.

I've made the `RewriteRule` *pattern* on the first rule more restrictive so as to avoid matching URLs of the form `/api<anything>` (eg. `/aping` or `/apiculture`) that should be routed to the frontend.

The `NC` flags would seem to be redundant, unless you specifically need to allow requests to `/API`, `/Api`, etc.

Might be relevant... you've not stated how you are handling static resources (if at all).

---

> ```
> RewriteRule ^api backend-directory [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ frontend-directory [NC]
> ```

Since you have omitted the `L` (or `END`) flag on the first rule, all requests will end up being rewritten to the `frontend-directory`. But also, since the trailing slash is omitted, you would also experience an external redirect.

Comment: I have tried your .htaccess code but that gives me following error

`Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request`

Comment: @fahadshaikh What version of Apache are you on? Do you have additional `.htaccess` files in the frontend and backend subdirectories? Do you have any other directives in the root `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @fahadshaikh When you get a 500 Internal Server Error, you should check the server's error log for details of the error. A 500 error is otherwise just a generic response that "something" went wrong.